# Aggregate two groups by total amount per day for animated plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the following data:

```
> as_tibble(animate)
# A tibble: 230 x 90
   user_id status_id created_at          screen_name text  source display_text_wi… reply_to_status…
   <chr>   <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>       <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <chr>           
 1 184795… 12738208… 2020-06-19 03:32:00 MLB         "Ins… Twitt…              152 NA              
 2 184795… 12738177… 2020-06-19 03:19:41 MLB         "Thi… Twitt…              117 NA              
 3 184795… 12737073… 2020-06-18 20:01:00 MLB         "“I’… Twitt…              140 NA              
 4 184795… 12737042… 2020-06-18 19:48:56 MLB         "As … Twitt…              140 NA              
 5 184795… 12736963… 2020-06-18 19:17:18 MLB         http… Twitt…               43 NA              
 6 184795… 12736623… 2020-06-18 17:02:24 MLB         .@du… Twitt…              138 NA              
 7 184795… 12733927… 2020-06-17 23:10:59 MLB         .@jo… Twitt…              100 NA              
 8 184795… 12732970… 2020-06-17 16:50:57 MLB         Now … Tweet…               60 NA              
 9 184795… 12732646… 2020-06-17 14:42:00 MLB         ".@s… Twitt…              171 NA              
10 184795… 12730685… 2020-06-17 01:43:00 MLB         "“It… Twitt…              213 NA
```

The 'screen_name' variable contains two different twitter handles (MLB, MLB_Player). I want to create an animated plot showing the total number of tweets per day from each twitter handle (screen_name).

I cannot seem to figure out how to structure the aggregate function to split the "screen_name" separately and then break each one down by date and the number of tweets one each day.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you probably don't even need to aggregate your data, just add "screen_name" as aesthetic. The data you are showing is a bit difficult to interpret for this purpose

Comment: Try something like `ggplot(your_df) + geom_bar(aes(x = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, unit = "days"), fill = screen_name), position = "dodge")` (Code a shot into the dark. you may need to convert your dttm column to date first, don't know if floor_date accepts dttm.)